# InkCanvas dynamic rendering of strokes

Tags: c#, uwp, win2d

In a UWP desktop app, I would like to use pen input to make simple brush strokes. I would like to render them *as the pen moves* to look like paint (so the InkCanvas's custom drying can't be done after the stroke is completed in OnStrokesCollected).

Can this type of dynamic custom drying be done with InkCanvas/InkPresenter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [CoreWetStrokeUpdateSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Input.Inking.Core.CoreWetStrokeUpdateSource) object to handle events to modify the ink as it's being drawing before it's rendered by the InkCanvas.  Depending on what you mean by 
"simple brush strokes" you can achieve some interesting effects.

Comment: Thank you, that is just what I was looking for with the Inking framework.